# Why isn't Unicode string retrived from Sybase register in Perl as Unicode?

Tags: perl, unicode, sybase

I have a string in a VARCHAR() column in a table in Sybase database which contains Unicode characters.

When I try to get that string, it gets returned, BUT, the UTF8 flag isn't set on it

```
my $sql = qq[select x from my_table where id=something];
my $sth = $dbHdl->prepare($sql);
eval { $results = $sth->execute() };
$cols = $sth->{NAME};
$results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
```

When I print $results from above code, it prints correct Unicode character:

```
  DB<4> x $results
0  ARRAY(0x93b02c0)
   0  HASH(0xbcf3700)
      'x' => 'Prefix € Suffix'
```

However, ***a check for whether it's a UTF8 string, returns false:***

```
  DB<8> x Encode::is_utf8($results->[0]->{x})
0  ''
```

As an extra check, `length()` call shows `17` instead of `15` as Unicode string would show.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change the connection string somehow?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - a bunch of bytes for the string, with "`.E2.82.AC.`" for the Euro character (which is a correct UTF8 set of bytes for it)

Comment: Have you tried [`syb_enable_utf8()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Sybase)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland no but don't they only apply to UNI* types?

Comment: Note that direct printing is never a good debugging tool for encoding issues. Your terminal expects a certain encoding (usually UTF-8) so that adds an additional layer to consider for any debugging (literally, if STDOUT has layers applied). Better is to print the ordinals of the string's character contents, which you can get in a nice dot-separated hex form using `sprintf '%vX', $string`.

Comment: Also note that the is_utf8 function has a misleading name and only indicates what the internal representation of the string is; it does not say anything about whether your string contains Unicode characters or bytes of some encoding as visible to Perl code. You can easily have a string of characters with the is_utf8 flag off provided they are all representable in your native single-byte encoding; or a string of random bytes can have the is_utf8 flag on, because some code ran utf8::upgrade or some XS code behaved weirdly or it's decoded from double-encoded characters.

Comment: All that to say, you didn't necessarily use it wrong here, but the logical contents of the string are wrong, not just the internal representation.